# Variadic Template Unpacking for Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I have an enum, as given below.
I want to have operator overloading for this enum,.

```
typedef enum E
{
    A = 1 << 0,
    B = 1 << 1,
    C = 1 << 2,
    D = 1 << 3,
    ANY = A | B | C | D,
}
E;

//Basic version

inline E operator |(E a, E b)
{
    return static_cast<E>(static_cast<int>(a) | static_cast<int>(b));
}

//Templated version
    template<typename T, typename Types>
    inline T operator |(T var1, Types var2) {
        return static_cast<T>(static_cast<unsigned int>(var1) | static_cast<unsigned int>(var2));
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Types>
    inline T operator |(T var1, Types... var2) {
        return static_cast<T>(static_cast<unsigned int>(var2...) | static_cast<unsigned int>(var1));
    }
```

I am getting following errors

```
error: expected ')'
        return static_cast<T>(static_cast<unsigned int>(var2...) | static_cast<unsigned int>(var1));
```

How do I correct it.

Thanks,

TechTotie.

Comment: `static_cast<unsigned int>(var2...)` does not do what you think it does. Handwaving the compilation error away: if, for example, `var2` would be a parameter pack with three values, is `static_cast<unsigned int>(1, 2, 4)` what you want to happen here? That would be the same as `static_cast<unsigned int>(4)`, so all you'll get is `4`, for your troubles. BTW, `|` is not, and cannot be, a variadic overload. There's really no such thing. You "correct" it by not doing it, the "basic" version is how it should be done.

Comment: You are looking for `static_cast<unsigned int>(var2)...`.

But the code has other flaws, both templates match `var1 | var2` and **more importantly** you have now defined or-ing of **any** types. That is surely not what you want, what are you trying to solve? The basic version should work just fine for `A | B | C | D`

Comment: How will the basic version work for ```A | B | C | D ``` ?

```static_cast<unsigned int>(var2)... ```also does not work.
I need to overload such that I can use enum as bit flags.

Comment: It works already the same way as `1+2+3+4+5`. In fact, since you are using the ordinary old enums, there is already a built-in operator so there is no need to define your own if you do not intend to provide custom behaviour.

Comment: @TechTotie Well, it would work if you wrote the fold expression correctly but it is not needed AFAIK. Please provide a [mcve] because [this works](https://godbolt.org/z/n4h7ecoY9).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
inline T operator | (T var1, Ts... var2)
{
    return static_cast<T>(  (static_cast<int>(var2) | ...) |  static_cast<int>(var1));
}
```

But

```
inline E operator |(E a, E b)
{
    return static_cast<E>(static_cast<int>(a) | static_cast<int>(b));
}
```

also can solve your problem